# get the matched data into array in javascript without using any loop

Tags: javascript, regex

Problem background -- I want to get the nth root of the number where user can enter expression like "the nth root of x'.I have written a function nthroot(x,n) which return proper expected output.My problem is to extract the value of x and n from expression.

I want to extract some matched pattern and store it to a an array for further processing so that in next step i will pop two elements from array and replace the result in repression.But I am unable to get all the values into an array without using loop.

A perl equivalent of my code will be like below.

```
$str = "the 2th root of 4+678+the 4th root of -10000x90";
@arr = $str =~ /the ([-+]?\d+)th\s?root\s?of\s?([-+]?\d+)/g;
print "@arr";
```

I want the javascript equivalent of  the above code.

or

any one line expression like below.

```
expr = expr.replace(/the\s?([+-]\d+)th\s?root\s?of([+-]\d+)/g,nthroot(\\$2,\\$1));
```

Please help me for the same.

Comment: can numbers be in hexadecimal form `-10000x90`??

Comment: and what is `4+678` in your input

Comment: no 'x' can be used instead of '*'. x is for multiplication operation.

Comment: $str = "the 2th root of 4+678+the 4th root of -10000x90";
basically it is a mathematical expression.User is allowed to enter in above form.So I need to convert it to its mathematical equivalent "2+678+(7.07106781+7.07106781i)*90" where i is root of -1(Complex number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that you are currently using is, as its name implies, used to do a string replacement, not to return the individual matches. It would make more sense to use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead, but you *can* (mis)use `.replace()` if you use a callback function:

```
var result = expr.replace(/the\s?([+-]\d+)th\s?root\s?of([+-]\d+)/,function(m,m1,m2){
  return nthroot(+m2, +m1);
});
```

Note that the arguments in the callback will be strings, so I'm converting them to numbers with the unary plus operator when passing them to your `nthroot()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex=/the ([-+]?\d+)th\s?root\s?of\s?([-+]?\d+)/g;
expr=expr.replace(regex, replaceCallback); 

var replaceCallback = function(match,p1,p2,offset, s) { 
 return nthroot(p2,p1);
 //p1 and p2 are similar to $1 $2
}
```